# svg rect radius with filter

Tags: html, svg

I ran into a problem that `rect` with `rx` specified doesn't work after applying filter to rect

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="floodFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood
        flood-color="#488764"
        flood-opacity="1" 
        result="background"
        />
        <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="background" />
    </filter>
    
    <linearGradient id="animation">
           <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(248, 222, 86, 0)"/>
           <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#65ae83"/>
        </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="200" filter="url(#floodFilter)" fill="url(#animation)" rx="8">
   <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" from="-100" to="100" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

So the question is how to apply the filter and keep the rx for the rectangle?

UPD: I can't use the fill attribute because fill is used for animation

UPD2: Added more examples with fill and filter and animation

Comment: animate the gradient stops and again don't use a filter.

Comment: How can I keep all green background and keep this animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a background rect with rounded corners:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="animation">
           <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(248, 222, 86, 0)"/>
           <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#65ae83"/>
        </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="200" height="200" rx="8" fill="#65ae83" />
  <rect width="100" height="200" fill="url(#animation)" rx="8">
   <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" from="0" to="100" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```